# While trying to access RedHat BRMS kie server, i am not able to use POST/PUT methods through rest client

Tags: drools, kie

Trying to access POST data through rest client, getting 405.

The response headers states  Allow: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD.

So how can I make my rest container accept POST/PUT methods?

EndPoint http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server  Request Headers used -
*Content-Type: application/json

authorization: Basic !@$#%&$*$(((
*Accept: application/json

X-KIE-ContentType: JSON*  RESPONSE HEADERS
S*erver: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Allow: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD

Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 1088

Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 08:43:33 GMT*

Tried using Advanced rest client,curl and java code but Same results :(
Referred - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BRMS/6.3/html/Getting_Started_Guide/chap-Hello_World_rule_example.html

Comment: fixed lines breaks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the Endpoint (URL). I would suggest

`http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/("nameOfYourDeployment")`

Or try without instances.

Answer (score 0):

In Rest Client provide the following set of values:

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/<name-of-your-container>
```

**HEADER:**

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

select method type `POST` and your `JSON request payload`

When you hit the API it will ask you for the username and password provide the credentials.

fou can send 
**payload**
as:

```
 {
 "commands": [
   {
     "insert": {
       "out-identifier": "Input",
       "return-object": "true",
       "object": {
         "<complete-package-name>.<class-name>": {
             "variable-1" : "value-1",  
             "variable-2" : "value-2"       
         }
       }
     }
   },
   {
     "fire-all-rules": {
       "outIdentifier": "output"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```